# Note unlink delete all files in array

Tags: node.js

I have an array with contains paths to files...

Example:

```
myarray = ['C\\myfiles\\file1.txt', 'C\\myfiles\\file1.jpg', 'C\\myfiles\\file2.png'];
```

I know how to delete a single file:

```
function myfunction() {
  const fs = require('fs')
  const path = './file.txt'

  try {
    fs.unlinkSync(path)
    //file removed
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

How can I delete the files inside the array instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the array with [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) method

```
const fs = require('fs')
myarray.forEach(path => {
    try {
    fs.unlinkSync(path)
      //file removed
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
});
```

> The **forEach()** method executes a provided function once for each array element.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the files in the array and delete them one by one

```
function myfunction() {
  const fs = require('fs')
  const paths = ['C\\myfiles\\file1.txt', 'C\\myfiles\\file1.jpg', 'C\\myfiles\\file2.png'];

  try {
    for (const file of paths) {
         fs.unlinkSync(file);
         //file removed
    }
     
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```